# Function: How to create a range from filtered cells using offset

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to finish my function where an average is take from values above the active cell. N is an input number for number of cells above active cell to be averaged.

The issue I'm having is that this will take the average of N cells, hidden or visible, above the active cell. I want this function to set a range from only visible cells.

I am attempting to incorporate ".SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)" but cannot get it to work. I am also avoiding subroutines.

```
Function MovingAVG_S2S(rng As Range, N As Integer) As Variant
 Dim rng2 As Range
 If rng <> 0 Then
 Set rng2 = rng.Offset(1 - N, 0).Resize(N, 1)
 MovingAVG_S2S = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng2)
 Else
 MovingAVG_S2S = ""
 End If
```

**EDIT 1**

For reference, I am averaging a range of values from Column P, the cell containing the function will be in Column R.

I want to take the average of "N" values above the cell with the function.

i.e., with an input of N = 90, and the function in cell R100, I want R to display an average of range P9:P99.

```
Function MovingAVG_S2S(ByVal top As Range, n As Long)
Dim sr As Long, sc As Long, er As Long, ec As Long
sr = top.Row
sc = top.Column
er = ActiveCell.Row
ec = ActiveCell.Column
MovingAVG_S2S = Application.Subtotal(101, Range(Cells(er - n, sc), Cells(er - 1, sc)))
```

Comment: You may be able to use SUBTOTAL()  - it can ignore hidden rows.  https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/subtotal-formula-explained/   You may need a loop to find the correct range to average over though.

Comment: @GMalc In trying to use what you had posted, changing N to offset will still select the hidden cell, just the number is smaller.  rows 1-10 exist and our UDF is in row 11, where rows 5 & 6 are hidden; the count of visible rows is 8, so the offset would start (1-8=) -7 rows offset, aka starting at row (11-7 =) 4, resulting in averaging values in rows 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, & 11 (resize to N more than start).  Did I miss something?